# Why below private method return 0 instead 15 in java?

Tags: java

```
public class Sacrifice {
    private int variableA = showOutput();
    private int variableB = 15;

    private int showOutput() {
        return variableB;
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        System.out.println( (new Sacrifice()).variableA);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in showOutput and run your program in the debugger

Answer (score 6):

Fields of a class are initialized in textual order.

That means that the initial value of `variableA` is computed **before** `variableB` has been initialized.   Therefore the `showOUtput()` method is seeing ... and returning ... the default initial value for `variableB`.   The default initial value for an `int` variable is `0`.

<sup>(This is all specified in the Java Language Specification, but I doubt that JLS references would be helpful for you ... at this stage.)</sup>

Comment: Yes ... it is a lot more complicated than that simple sentence.  There are also `static` variables, blank initializations, initializer blocks and constructors to consider.   But if you just have simple instance fields with (non-blank) initializers as per the example, then "in textual order" covers it.